# How to ensure all consumers can read all data from Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

We have a node.js application that needs to receive the messages from kafka, and if the application autoscales all the instances of the application should receive all the messages.

Will it be a good approach to generate a randon string when the application starts and use it as a consumer group id to connect to kafka?

This way all the instances will receive all the messages, but i am not sure if this is the correct approach
considering autoscaled intances might have a very short lifespan and the number of instances can change very quickly, and each instance will
join with as completely new consumer group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have all instances reading all messages in a Kafka Topic then there is no alternative but having a unique Consumer Group for each instance.

You will probably end up with a lot of "dead" Consumer groups but that will just create one unnecessary message for each Consumer Group in the internal Kafka topic `__consumer_offsets` which should not be a problem in terms of data volume.

Comment: Thanks for the response Mike, now the question is, say the messages are coming like this 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9....
And there is a consumer group 'A' for the main instance of the application, it read the messages 1,2,3, and at this moment
because of autoscaling there comes other instance and creates consumer group 'B'.
Now it start consuming messages starting from 3 (in parallel to consumer 'A') and than consumer 'B' dies.
Now will kafka keeps storing the messages from 7 onwards for consumer 'B' to come online?
Or will it remove the messages once consumed by 'A'.

Comment: Kafka will keep storing messages even after they were consumed by other consumers. This is a major distinction of Kafka to other Pub/Sub messaging systems. Kafka stores the message in a topic based on retention configuration and all messages can be consumed by multiple consumers independently.